# iOS 4 resume from background

Tags: objective-c, iphone, multitasking

It is possible to get a notification or something when the user opens the application, but the application was in the background (so it wasn't closed)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your App Delegate will have its function **applicationWillEnterForeground** called before coming back.

Also, the OS will have queued a series of potential notifications for significant OS changes if it were freeze dried when those events were fired, ie: **UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification** and **UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification**