# how to restart a game

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

i am making ticTacToe

and when i press back button in the iphone it quit normally but when i turn back to the game it reseted automatically

and i didint type any code to reset it in the viewDidLoad method

but what i need now is this

how to make the same thing by pressing [reset button] in the iphone ? 
i tried to make this

```
    ViewController *SP=[[SinglePlayer alloc]init];
   [SP viewDidUnload]; 
   [SP viewDidLoad];
```

but it didnt succeeded  , but it shows me an NSLog i typed it in each one so videDidLoad and viewDidUnload ran successfully

so i want to release all data was saved and begin with a new game when press [reset] as it has been automatically when pressed back

Answer (score 1):

Is your application configured to **Suspend** instead of **Exit**?

If you're unsure there is a brief explanation [here](http://devgirl.org/2011/06/24/exit-vs-suspend-your-ios-application/) and a related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531014/ios-4-resume-from-background).

Finally, see *"App States and Multitasking"* [in the iOS App Programming Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531014/ios-4-resume-from-background).

Comment: unfortunately, nobody will write your code for you here, they will mostly direct you to a right direction or give you little code snippets.